# Создание динамического массива данных

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Каким образом создать m динамических массивов, причем длина каждого 8бит, а ширина задается случайным числом, например, может быть в промежутке от 1 мбайта до 1 ггбайта. И после создания промаркировать их случайным образом!  Пример: сгенерировать 32 массива, каждый из них длиной 8 бит шириной 1 мбайт и каждый массив должен заполняться 0 и 1, способ заполнения следующий: допустим, из 32 5с маркером 1 и сначала запишется первые 8 бит в первый такой, затем во второй, потом приступаем к заполнению массивов с маркером 2 и так далее.

Comment: Вам нужны двумерные массивы?

Comment: Ширина и длина массива - это круто.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> допустим из 32 5с маркером 1 и сначала запишется первые 8 бит в первый такой, затем во второй , потом приступаем к заполнению массивов с маркером 2 и так далее

Из того, что здесь написано, ясно только то, что требуется побитовый доступ в двумерном битовом массиве,

а вот остальное все просто:

```
width   = 1024 * 1024     
bytes   = 32 * width;
p       = new BYTE[ bytes ];
```

в p - 32 двумерных битовых массива,
поставить бит можно так:

```
ID = n * width * 8 + bit;
p[ID] |= ( 1 << ( ID % 8 ) );
```

а снять так:

```
p[ID] &= ~( 1 << ( ID % 8 ) );
```

n - номер массива (от 0 до 31)
bit - номер бита в этом массиве, который и нужно поставить/снять (от 0 до width * 8 - 1)

> Мультиплексор надо написать! Да так и задумано, количество меток определяет пользователь

Тогда можно сделать так:

```
num_channels = 32;
labels       = new INT[ num_channels ];
width        = 1024 * 1024; /* один МБайт */
p            = new BYTE[ num_channels * width ];
...
for( lbl = 0 ; lbl < num_labels ; ++lbl ){
  for( i = 0 ; i < num_channels ; ++i ){
    if( labels[i] == lbl ){
      set_label_array( lbl, p + i * width );
    }
  }
}
```

`num_channels` - число каналов ( массивов )
`num_labels` - число меток
`labels` - массив соответствий массивов меткам, который можно произвольно заполнять и менять
`set_label_array` - метод, который должен заполнить очередной массив, помеченный меткой `lbl`

Comment: Извиняюсь за сбивчивость и неясность задачи. Поясню по-другому! Мне необходимо сгенерировать к примеру 32 массива, каждый из них равен по длине одному байту,а сколько вниз не ограничивается! Затем я начинаю их заполнять, при этом заполнения происходит следующим образом :по очереди записывается по 8 бит в 0, 1, 2,5 и допустим 7 массив, это массивы с меткой 1, затем так же какие -то принадлежат метке 2 и так далее, меток может быть много но допустим для примера что их 4 получается в каждой метке по 8 массивов!  А потом происходит заполнения, сначала массивов с меткой один, потом 2 ну и т. Д.

Comment: Все равно, не очень понятно. Что это за задача, если не секрет? В таком случае меток не может быть много, их будет максимум 32. Так и задумано?

Comment: нет их сначала будет 32 а потом с шагом 64 будут меняться ! Мультиплексор надо написать

Comment: Тогда можно сделать так:

 num_channels = 32;
 labels       = new INT[num_channels];
 width        = 1024*1024;
 p            = new BYTE[num_channels * width];
 ...
 for( lbl = 0 ; lbl < num_labels ; ++lbl ){
   for( i = 0 ; i < num_channels ; ++i ){
     if( labels[i] == lbl ){
       set_label_array(lbl,p + i*width);
     }
   }
 }
`num_channels` - число каналов ( массивов )  
`num_labels` - число меток  
`labels` - массив соответствий массивов меткам, который можно произвольно заполнять и менять  
`set_label_array` - метод, который должен заполнить очередной массив, помеченный меткой `lbl`

Comment: Теперь все ясно,надеюсь получится реализовать,а то уже хотел начинать разбираться в bitarray Stl библиотеки